# Confusion with Bayesian Linear Regression

Tags: regression, bayesian

In the book Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning in Chapter 2 p. 11 (see http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf), eq. 2.9 states:

> $p(f_* | X, y) = \int p(f_* | x_*,w) p(w|X, y)dw$

the posterior predictive function.

I have huge difficulties trying to understand what $p(f_* | x_*, w)$ should look like. Since $f_* = f(x_*) = x_*^T w$ is uniquely determined, should I imagine this PDF as $0$ everywhere except at $x_*^T w$? How would it this PDF be written explicetly? How does one go about solving this integral?

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm writing this as a comment since I'm not sure if it answers your question. If $Y=Xb + e$ and $e$~$N(0,\sigma^2)$ then $Pr(y<Y) = Pr(\frac{y-Xb}{\sigma}<\frac{Y-Xb}{\sigma}) = \Phi(\frac{Y-Xb}{\sigma}))$ where $\Phi$ represents the standard normal cdf, which implies that the pdf is $f(Y)=\phi(\frac{Y-Xb}{\sigma})$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So this means $p(f_*|x_*, w) = e^{\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}(f_*-x_*^Tw)^T (f_*-x_*^Tw)}$?